# Magento meta keywords tag not showing

Tags: magento, seo, meta-tags

Below line of code is present in my template's head.phtml

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
```

But when I view source of page the meta keywords tag is missing. Somehow Magento is removing the entire tag.

Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due to `Creare SEO` extension.

Comment: so I should remove this extension?

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh the Magento cache?

```
System --> Cache Management
```

Maybe also clear your browser cache.

If this doesn't work, try adding a dummy meta tag:

Then refresh the cache again:

```
System --> Cache Management
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I did clear cache, all other dummy meta tags work fine, only the tag  with the name "keywords" is not showing up.

Comment: even if I change `keywords` to `keywords1` its shows up but it doesn't show if I name it `keywords`

Comment: Are you using a bought theme? Could be that they overwrite the base settings (would be really bad, but still..). Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, I am using a premium theme.

Comment: I would recommend you to contact the theme builder. For others with the same problem it would be great if you tell us what the final solution was.

Answer (score 0):

did you edit the code in your template folder or the core base? you have to edit the default head.phtml in

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html

and if this is where you changed it, make sure you save your old version in-case you need to revert back, in this case i usually just add () around the file name so i know its the previous version. Now try the following new version. the code should be the following:

```
<?php
/**
* Magento
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
* needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
*
* @category    design
* @package     base_default
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc.    (http://www.magento.com)
* @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic  Free License (AFL 3.0)
*/
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this-   >getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this-   >getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this-   >getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this-   >getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
 var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')- >getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
enter code here
```

Once you have reverted, log in to your admin panel, navigate to system/configuration/design scroll down and enter your keywords into the field. Separate each with a comma. Sign out of admin.  Clear the browser cache, and sign back in.

Comment: good call RoRo.  Good rule of thumb, after any change in magento clear the cache via the admin, and refresh the blocks

Comment: my template's head.phtml already have a meta tag for keywords but that tag is not showing, all others show.

Comment: Is there anyways we can see what you are working with now as far as code?  The full snippet?

Answer (score 0):

As @tahir-yasin mention this is due to Creare SEO, but you don't need to uninstall this extension. Go to your Settings>Configuration> 
In CREARE SEO find General Settings and change "
Disable Meta Keywords Tag and Empty Meta Description Tags?" to "No" your problem will be solved..